# Implementing the Matlab fspecial-function in R

Tags: r, matlab, 2d, blur, gaussian

I need to calculate the Structural Similarity (SSIM) index in R, and can only find the method implemented in Matlab. Re-writing the method in R seem quite straight forward except for the two Matlab methods "fspecial" and "filter2".

fspecial returns a 2D gaussian distribution in a 11x11 matrix with standard diviation 1.5:

```
h = fspecial('gaussian', 11, 1.5)
```

So I  have implemented a function that should do the same in R with a little help found online:

```
gaussian2D <- function(amplitude) {
  # Defining limits of grid
  x_min <- 1
  x_max <- 11
  y_min <- x_min
  y_max <- x_max

  # Setting parameters of the two-dimensional Gaussian function 
  # The distribution is centred in [6,6]
  x_zero <- 6
  y_zero <- 6

  # Setting the spread of the filter
  sigma_x <- 1.5
  sigma_y <- sigma_x

  # Running through all x and y combinations applying the 2d-gaussian equation
  df <- NULL
  for (x_val in c(x_min:x_max)){
    for (y_val in c(y_min:y_max)){
      cell_value <- amplitude*exp(-( (((x_val-x_zero)^2)/(2*(sigma_x^2))) +     (((y_val-y_zero)^2)/(2*(sigma_y^2))) ))
      df = rbind(df,data.frame(x_val,y_val, cell_value))
    }
  }

  # Axis labels
  x_axis <- c(x_min:x_max)
  y_axis <- c(y_min:y_max)

  # Populating matrix
  gauss_matrix <- matrix(df[,3], nrow = 11, ncol = 11, dimnames = list(x_axis,     y_axis))

  return(gauss_matrix)
}

h2 = gaussian2D(1)
```

However, strangely when I run the two methods, I do not get the same result but rather I get a matrices scaled by 14.13:

```
h2/h

   1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11
1  14.13137 14.13185 14.13201 14.13238 14.13187 14.13189 14.13187 14.13238 14.13201 14.13185 14.13137
2  14.13185 14.13186 14.13189 14.13175 14.13164 14.13154 14.13164 14.13175 14.13189 14.13186 14.13185
3  14.13201 14.13189 14.13135 14.13172 14.13176 14.13187 14.13176 14.13172 14.13135 14.13189 14.13201
4  14.13238 14.13175 14.13172 14.13155 14.13209 14.13194 14.13209 14.13155 14.13172 14.13175 14.13238
5  14.13187 14.13164 14.13176 14.13209 14.13194 14.13182 14.13194 14.13209 14.13176 14.13164 14.13187
6  14.13189 14.13154 14.13187 14.13194 14.13182 14.13188 14.13182 14.13194 14.13187 14.13154 14.13189
7  14.13187 14.13164 14.13176 14.13209 14.13194 14.13182 14.13194 14.13209 14.13176 14.13164 14.13187
8  14.13238 14.13175 14.13172 14.13155 14.13209 14.13194 14.13209 14.13155 14.13172 14.13175 14.13238
9  14.13201 14.13189 14.13135 14.13172 14.13176 14.13187 14.13176 14.13172 14.13135 14.13189 14.13201
10 14.13185 14.13186 14.13189 14.13175 14.13164 14.13154 14.13164 14.13175 14.13189 14.13186 14.13185
11 14.13137 14.13185 14.13201 14.13238 14.13187 14.13189 14.13187 14.13238 14.13201 14.13185 14.13137
```

Does anyone have a suggestion to what is I have done wrong?

Comment: On a tangential note, you may take a look at `outer` and `expand.grid`. They may be used to alleviate your nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the adjustment term: 1/(2*pi*sigma1*sigma2)

Note that 2*pi*1.5*1.5 = 14.13717

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering where that number came from! I was trying all sorts of manipulations with pi, but this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB, `fspecial` also **normalizes** the kernel so that the total sum of all elements in the kernel is equal to 1.  This is because when performing convolution with this kernel, it avoids producing any output values that are beyond the dynamic range of the data type that is associated with the signal you are trying to filter.

This also avoids having to use any adjustment terms as stated previously by @imo.  Very simply, you aren't normalizing the kernel in your code.  Therefore, inside your loop have an extra summation term that sums over every Gaussian term, then the final matrix should divide every entry by this amount:

```
  df <- NULL
  s <- 0 # Added
  for (x_val in c(x_min:x_max)){
    for (y_val in c(y_min:y_max)){
      cell_value <- amplitude*exp(-( (((x_val-x_zero)^2)/(2*(sigma_x^2))) +     (((y_val-y_zero)^2)/(2*(sigma_y^2))) ))
      df = rbind(df,data.frame(x_val,y_val, cell_value))
      s <- s + cell_value # Added
    }
  }
```

Finally when you return the matrix:

```
return(gauss_matrix / s)
```

To double-check, in MATLAB this is what you get when you make your call to `fspecial`:

```
>> format long g
>> h = fspecial('gaussian', 11, 1.5)

h =

  Columns 1 through 3

      1.05756559815326e-06       7.8144115330536e-06      3.70224770827489e-05
       7.8144115330536e-06      5.77411251978637e-05      0.000273561160085806
      3.70224770827489e-05      0.000273561160085806        0.0012960555938432
      0.000112464355116679      0.000831005429087199       0.00393706926284678
      0.000219050652866017       0.00161857756253439       0.00766836382523672
      0.000273561160085806       0.00202135875836257       0.00957662749024029
      0.000219050652866017       0.00161857756253439       0.00766836382523672
      0.000112464355116679      0.000831005429087199       0.00393706926284678
      3.70224770827489e-05      0.000273561160085806        0.0012960555938432
       7.8144115330536e-06      5.77411251978637e-05      0.000273561160085806
      1.05756559815326e-06       7.8144115330536e-06      3.70224770827489e-05

  Columns 4 through 6

      0.000112464355116679      0.000219050652866017      0.000273561160085806
      0.000831005429087199       0.00161857756253439       0.00202135875836257
       0.00393706926284678       0.00766836382523672       0.00957662749024029
         0.011959760410037        0.0232944324734871        0.0290912256485504
        0.0232944324734871        0.0453713590956603        0.0566619704916846
        0.0290912256485504        0.0566619704916846         0.070762237763947
        0.0232944324734871        0.0453713590956603        0.0566619704916846
         0.011959760410037        0.0232944324734871        0.0290912256485504
       0.00393706926284678       0.00766836382523672       0.00957662749024029
      0.000831005429087199       0.00161857756253439       0.00202135875836257
      0.000112464355116679      0.000219050652866017      0.000273561160085806

  Columns 7 through 9

      0.000219050652866017      0.000112464355116679      3.70224770827489e-05
       0.00161857756253439      0.000831005429087199      0.000273561160085806
       0.00766836382523672       0.00393706926284678        0.0012960555938432
        0.0232944324734871         0.011959760410037       0.00393706926284678
        0.0453713590956603        0.0232944324734871       0.00766836382523672
        0.0566619704916846        0.0290912256485504       0.00957662749024029
        0.0453713590956603        0.0232944324734871       0.00766836382523672
        0.0232944324734871         0.011959760410037       0.00393706926284678
       0.00766836382523672       0.00393706926284678        0.0012960555938432
       0.00161857756253439      0.000831005429087199      0.000273561160085806
      0.000219050652866017      0.000112464355116679      3.70224770827489e-05

  Columns 10 through 11

       7.8144115330536e-06      1.05756559815326e-06
      5.77411251978637e-05       7.8144115330536e-06
      0.000273561160085806      3.70224770827489e-05
      0.000831005429087199      0.000112464355116679
       0.00161857756253439      0.000219050652866017
       0.00202135875836257      0.000273561160085806
       0.00161857756253439      0.000219050652866017
      0.000831005429087199      0.000112464355116679
      0.000273561160085806      3.70224770827489e-05
      5.77411251978637e-05       7.8144115330536e-06
       7.8144115330536e-06      1.05756559815326e-06
```

... and finally in R:

```
> h2
              1            2            3            4            5            6            7
1  1.057566e-06 7.814412e-06 3.702248e-05 0.0001124644 0.0002190507 0.0002735612 0.0002190507
2  7.814412e-06 5.774113e-05 2.735612e-04 0.0008310054 0.0016185776 0.0020213588 0.0016185776
3  3.702248e-05 2.735612e-04 1.296056e-03 0.0039370693 0.0076683638 0.0095766275 0.0076683638
4  1.124644e-04 8.310054e-04 3.937069e-03 0.0119597604 0.0232944325 0.0290912256 0.0232944325
5  2.190507e-04 1.618578e-03 7.668364e-03 0.0232944325 0.0453713591 0.0566619705 0.0453713591
6  2.735612e-04 2.021359e-03 9.576627e-03 0.0290912256 0.0566619705 0.0707622378 0.0566619705
7  2.190507e-04 1.618578e-03 7.668364e-03 0.0232944325 0.0453713591 0.0566619705 0.0453713591
8  1.124644e-04 8.310054e-04 3.937069e-03 0.0119597604 0.0232944325 0.0290912256 0.0232944325
9  3.702248e-05 2.735612e-04 1.296056e-03 0.0039370693 0.0076683638 0.0095766275 0.0076683638
10 7.814412e-06 5.774113e-05 2.735612e-04 0.0008310054 0.0016185776 0.0020213588 0.0016185776
11 1.057566e-06 7.814412e-06 3.702248e-05 0.0001124644 0.0002190507 0.0002735612 0.0002190507
              8            9           10           11
1  0.0001124644 3.702248e-05 7.814412e-06 1.057566e-06
2  0.0008310054 2.735612e-04 5.774113e-05 7.814412e-06
3  0.0039370693 1.296056e-03 2.735612e-04 3.702248e-05
4  0.0119597604 3.937069e-03 8.310054e-04 1.124644e-04
5  0.0232944325 7.668364e-03 1.618578e-03 2.190507e-04
6  0.0290912256 9.576627e-03 2.021359e-03 2.735612e-04
7  0.0232944325 7.668364e-03 1.618578e-03 2.190507e-04
8  0.0119597604 3.937069e-03 8.310054e-04 1.124644e-04
9  0.0039370693 1.296056e-03 2.735612e-04 3.702248e-05
10 0.0008310054 2.735612e-04 5.774113e-05 7.814412e-06
11 0.0001124644 3.702248e-05 7.814412e-06 1.057566e-06
```

... looks like it matches to me!

Comment: Thanks, I now produces that I would like!